# Merging .NET 4.0 Tasks/continuations of different types

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, task, async-await

I'm currently implementing a `System.Web.Http.IActionFilter` which calls an internal service to determine whether the current request can continue. The problem I'm having is returning a `Task<T1>` based on a piece of logic encapsulated by a `Task<T2>`.

An example might help.

The internal service API is implemented using Tasks. The logic is trivial using **.NET 4.5**'s async/await:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    UserAuthenticationResult authResult = await HitInternalServiceAsync();

    if (!authResult.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException("User is not authenticated", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    return await continuation();
}
```

However it is more difficult with the old Task API in **.NET 4.0**;

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    return HitInternalServiceAsync()
            .ContinueWith(t1 => {
                UserAuthenticationResult authResult = t1.Result;

                if (!authResult.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException("User is not authenticated", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }

                //Hack hack - this blocks the thread until the task retuned by continuation() completes
                return continuation().Result;
            });
}
```

The difficult part comes when the authentication check has succeeded - I then want to await the task returned by the continuation function.

Using .NET 4.0 it looks like I have explicitly block when waiting for the `continuation()` task to complete, rather than instructing the Tasks API to automatically continue with the `continuation()` task when *my task* is done.

### The question: Is this the only way to implement this behaviour in .NET 4.0?

Given a sufficiently complicated internal service API, I can easily see the number of Tasks waiting on other Tasks multiplying quickly.

**EDIT:** Looks like the above **4.0** code isn't viable either - because the continuation lambda does not execute in the ASP.NET thread context services like HttpContext.Current are not available. A better implementation would be...

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    Task<UserAuthenticationResult> authResultTask = HitInternalServiceAsync();

    var authResult = authResultTask.Result;

    if (!authResult.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException("User is not authenticated", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    return continuation();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that if you don't use `Result`, `ContinueWith()` will return `Task<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>` and not the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` you need.

Fortunately, there already is a method that converts any `Task<Task<T>>` to `Task<T>`: [`Unwrap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781129.aspx). So just `return continuation();` from the `ContinueWith()` lambda and then call `Unwrap()` on the result.

If you want the continuation to execute in the ASP.NET context, you can use [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx).

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for - I felt like this was such an obvious use-case, it seemed strange that the API didn't seem to really support it. Luckily I was wrong!

Answer (score 3):

> The question: Is this the only way to implement this behaviour in .NET 4.0?

`async`/`await` is a C# 5.0 feature, not a .NET 4.5 feature. It does make use of some types introduced in .NET 4.5, but there's no other reason it would require a new runtime.

svick's answer is the best if you're using VS2010 (C# 4.0).

However, there is another option if you're using VS11 Beta (C# 5.0): you can use the [async targeting pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/04/26/async-targeting-pack-for-visual-studio-11-now-available-for-net-4-and-silverlight-5-greg.aspx) to write `async`/`await` code that runs on .NET 4.0. The targeting pack has those new types for .NET 4.0.

Comment: You're correct in that I meant C# 5.0 targeting .NET 4.5 for the first example. The heads up about the `async targeting pack` is also appreciated - we would like to use async\await but requirements currently have us targeting the 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

instead of continuation().Result
use continuation().Wait()

task.wait is the appropriate way to block a task.

As per MSDN documentation,
Task.Wait Method: Waits for the Task to complete execution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx

Folowing seems related question, that answers 
[Do the new C# 5.0 'async' and 'await' keywords use multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898441/do-the-new-c-sharp-5-0-async-and-await-keywords-use-multiple-cores)

Comment: A quick dip into the IL shows that `.Result` calls `.Wait()` internally

Comment: `Wait()` and `Result` act exactly the same with regards to blocking and waiting, neither of them is more appropriate than the other.

Comment: Wait() certainly seems more explicit in certain cases if you want it to read like that