# using dependency properties along with async ctp

Tags: c#, mvvm, async-ctp, xunit.net

I have created some sample ViewModel to test usage of DPs with asyncCtp:

```
public class SampleVm : DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SampleDependencyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SampleDependencyProperty", typeof (int), typeof (SampleVm), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int SampleDependencyProperty
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(SampleDependencyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SampleDependencyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }
    public ISampleModel _model;
    public SampleVm(ISampleModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public async Task SetDependencyProperty()
    {
        var modelData = await TaskEx.Run(() => _model.GetSomeIntegerValue());
        SampleDependencyProperty = modelData;
    }
}
```

and the model which injected to ViewModel is:

```
public interface ISampleModel
{
    int GetSomeIntegerValue();
}

public class SampleModel : ISampleModel
{
    public int GetSomeIntegerValue()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

when I run the WPF application there is no problem, but when I want to test it with the following code:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CheckValueSetting()
{
    var model = new Mock<ISampleModel>();
    model.Setup(x => x.GetSomeIntegerValue()).Returns(5);
    var viewModel =new SampleVm(model.Object);

    await viewModel.SetDependencyProperty();

    Assert.Equal(5, viewModel.SampleDependencyProperty);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Server stack trace: 

    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    at WpfApplication4.SampleVm.set_SampleDependencyProperty(Int32 value) in SampleVM.cs: line 19
    at WpfApplication4.SampleVm.<SetDependencyProperty>d__1.MoveNext() in SampleVM.cs: line 30

    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    at WpfApplication4.SampleVmFixture.<CheckValueSetting>d__0.MoveNext() in SampleVmFixture.cs: line 16
```

so what is the solution?

Comment: Can I check: why are you still using the async CTP? Isn't that all in core .NET now?

Comment: I have to use .Net framework 4 because of the restrictions in the company.

Comment: that makes precisely no sense. By definition a CTP is completely unsupported, and in this case is now obsolete. There is no universe where using a CTP is a better option than facing the upgrade. IMO: take the upgrade (even if that means some work internally), or forget about async. Finally: much of the async stuff is in 4.0 anyway!!!

Comment: Targeting .NET 4 makes sense, particularly since the "in-place" 4.5 upgrade doesn't support XP. He probably just doesn't know about Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Comment: thanks to @MarcGravell and StephenCleary  for their suggestions. after reading this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898441/do-the-new-c-sharp-5-0-async-and-await-keywords-use-multiple-cores/9899487#9899487) and this [blog on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/17/async-ctp-refresh-what-bugs-remain-in-it.aspx) I think the solution is not to continue with AsyncCtp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend that you upgrade to VS2012 with the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx). This will enable you to target .NET 4.0 with the newest tools. The Async CTP has known bugs that will not be fixed, and it has installation issues (that won't be fixed) that will make setting up new development machines quite difficult.

But before you delete the Async CTP, check out your `(C# Testing) Unit Testing` directory under the Async CTP directory. You'll find several types to help with unit testing, such as `GeneralThreadAffineContext`:

```
[Fact]
public async Task CheckValueSetting()
{
    var model = new Mock<ISampleModel>();
    model.Setup(x => x.GetSomeIntegerValue()).Returns(5);
    SampleVm viewModel;
    await GeneralThreadAffineContext.Run(async () =>
    {
        viewModel = new SampleVm(model.Object);
        await viewModel.SetDependencyProperty();
    });

    Assert.Equal(5, viewModel.SampleDependencyProperty);
}
```

Comment: The example from the CTP is not available elsewhere? Also, I think you forgot to `await` the result of `Run()`.

Comment: I'm not aware of an official source for the "extras" from the Async CTP; `AsyncContext` in my AsyncEx library is a pretty close match for `GeneralThreadAffineContext`, but I'm not aware of anything equivalent to `WindowsFormsContext` or `WpfContext`. Also, `Run` returns `void` (it does not complete until all `async` methods have completed).

Comment: The `GeneralThreadAffineContext` I have has several overloads of `Run()`: `void Run(Action asyncAction)` and `Task Run(Func<Task> asyncMethod)` and since you're using the second one, I think you have to `await` it.

Comment: @svick: You are correct; I had modified my copy. Technically, that `Run` overload will wait for the `async` method to complete, but there's no harm in `await`ing it.