# Async/await and parallel in C#

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, parallel.foreach

When should I use async/await and when should I use parallel.foreach in C#? Are parallel and async/await serve the same purpose? 
What are the differences in them?

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898441/do-the-new-c-sharp-5-0-async-and-await-keywords-use-multiple-cores

Comment: See how to call async operations in parallel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/11565531#11565531

Comment: How is this not constructive?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

async/await is about *asynchrony*, whereas `Parallel.ForEach` is about *parallelism*. They're related concepts, but not the same.

`Parallel.ForEach` is used when you want to execute the same operation on all the items in a collection, in parallel, blocking the current thread until all operations have completed.

async/await is used when the current operation can't make any more progress until a particular asynchronous operation has completed, but you don't want to block the current thread. This is particularly useful in two situations:

- Writing code which basically kicks off various asynchronous operations, one after the other, on the UI thread, accessing the UI briefly between operations. (It's more general than that, but that's a simple example.) You don't want to block the UI thread, but managing all of those asynchronous operations is a pain otherwise.
- Handling *lots* of long-running operations at a time - e.g. in a web server. Each individual request may take a long time due to calling into other web service, databases etc - but you don't want to have one thread per request, as threads are a relatively expensive resource.

You can combine parallelism and asynchrony by kicking off a new task which will call `Parallel.ForEach`, and then awaiting that task. (Just as one example.)