# C# - Async method in SELECT LINQ operation

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

Let's consider this code :

```
var tasks = actionItems.Select(t => DoSmthAsync());
var resultAll = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

And method:

```
public async Task<int> DoSmthAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Threadid=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var result = await DoSmthAnotherAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("ThreadId=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return result;
}
```

I expect that this will be executed parallel in different threads, but I see that it work in the same thread. Also, I don't understand when a task run?

Comment: Hi, asynchrony does not mean parallelism, so expectation to use different threads is not correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099520/async-await-and-parallel-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you post  the code for `DoSmthAnotherAsync`?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console application? Windows Forms?

Comment: The bigger question is why do you care about threads using async?  Async reduces thread usage.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the `async await` model with parallel programming.

`Select` will iterate over your `actionItems` serially.  `DoSmthAsync` will return control to the caller (the `Select` iterator in this case) when you await `DoSmthAnotherAsync` and so you get a list of `Task<int>` created on one thread.

To run the `Select` statement in paralell, you'll need to use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq).

```
var tasks = actionItems.AsParallel().Select(t => DoSmthAsync());
```

This will produce your anticipated results.

You will then need to `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to wait for the results of the tasks.  Then you can access the result of each `Task<int>` in your `tasks` list with their respective `Result` properties.

Comment: The `AsParallel` will only **start** the tasks in parallel. The OP is probably interested in the whole execution of the tasks, from start to completion.

Comment: It seems like his priority is that computation occurs on multiple threads.  I've edited my post to include a method to retrieve the results of the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I don't understand when a task run?

A `Task` is usually started when it is created (in which case it is called a *hot* task). Async methods and almost all built-in APIs return hot tasks. It is possible to create a non-started `Task` by using the `Task` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor) (creating a so called *cold* task), but this is unusual and not recommended.

> This constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated.

```
var tasks = actionItems.Select(t => DoSmthAsync());
```

This line of code doesn't create any tasks, so no task is started at this point. The [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) LINQ method returns a deferred enumerable, not a materialized collection. The actual materialization of the tasks happens when you call the method `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`.