# Async Await Infinite Regression

Tags: c#

You can only await an async method. However that async method itself needs to have an await statement inside it itself.
Doesn't this lead to an infinite regression?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9898441/326543). Besides @JaredPar has summarized it beautifully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can only await an async method.

That's not true. You can await anything that follows the "awaitable pattern" (something with a `GetAwaiter()` method, the return type of which has appropriate `IsCompleted`, `GetResult()`, and `OnCompleted()` members.

Note that even when you're awaiting the result of calling an async method, it really is the *result* that you're awaiting... and it doesn't matter that the result *happened* to be from an async method. As far as the compiler's concerned, you're just awaiting a `Task` or a `Task<T>`, which was the result of a method call. The `async` part *only* matters within the implementation of the method.

You can await other things as well though - for example, [`Task.Yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a [`YieldAwaitable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.yieldawaitable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which isn't a task, but which implements the awaitable pattern. You can implement the awaitable pattern yourself (and cause all kinds of fun mayhem by doing so, should you wish to).

> However that async method itself needs to have an await statement inside it itself.

Again, not true - although the compiler will warn you if you *don't* have an await expression within an async method, as that's almost always a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

No for a couple of reasons

- An `async` method is not required to have an `await`, it's just recomended
- An `await` expression can target items like `Task<T>`
- An `async` method can be called from a non-async method

Here is a simple example that has terminates

```
async Task<int> Add(Task<int> task, int value) { 
  var t = await task;
  return t + value;
}

Task<int> t;
Task<int> t2 = Add(t, 42);
```